# How copy all Categories attributes for store view A to default store view

Tags: magento2, database, query

I would like to copy categories attributes (e.g title, search engine optimization text like url_key, contents, description etc) from a store view navigation to the default navigation.

In other words, I would like to use the categories in All Store View instead of my store view. However, I have been mistakenly editing the store view categories instead of the global ones and it's time-consuming to re-update that manually.

How to copy these:

[image]

To these:

[image]

Therefore what is a good approach to do this?

I'm not sure if doing this is correct, but I tried editing directly the table. Not sure if there are other considerations I need to put into mind when editing the table directly.

I thought to copy all records from store id 1 to store id 0 and then delete everything in store id 0 in order to reset it to use (**Use Default Value**)

```
INSERT INTO  `catalog_category_entity_text` (
  `attribute_id`,
  `store_id`,
  `entity_id`,
  `value`
) 
SELECT 
  `attribute_id`,
  "0",
  `entity_id`,
  `value` 
FROM
  `catalog_category_entity_text_1` src 
WHERE src.`store_id` = 1 AND src.value IS NOT NULL
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE 
    `catalog_category_entity_text`.`value` = src.`value` ;
```

Comment: I may not have a solution right now, but I can say that your approach would not work for you.  The `store_id` in these tables is the [scope of the settings value](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html) where `1` would be your store-level, and `0` is global.  What you need to look at is the `catalog_category_entity` table, specifically the `path` column.  You can copy the categories with different paths there, but you would still have to populate all of the tables in my next comment...

Comment: catalog_category_entity_int, catalog_category_entity_text, catalog_category_entity_decimal, catalog_category_entity_datetime, catalog_category_entity_varchar, and catalog_category_product will all need to be populated with the new categories **and their new ids**

Comment: @mtr.web thank you for your reply. The categories actually exist in both store, I wanted to copy their descriptions etc to global categories.  I managed to do that by running a few queries. I added an answer. Again, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an answer for my future reference.

So I did a three-step insert & update to copy the details of categories in Store view #1 to categories to the global categories store ID #0.

The operation I did was on these tables (I skipped decimal and DateTime as I never selected any of these options)

**1)** First I backed up these tables _1:

```
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
catalog_category_entity_int
```

**2)** I ran the following query for all 3 tables. This will insert all edited fields from Store ID#1 in case they were never populated in Store ID#0.

```
INSERT INTO  `catalog_category_entity_<datatype>` (
  `attribute_id`,
  `store_id`,
  `entity_id`,
  `value`
) 
SELECT 
  `attribute_id`,
  "0",
  `entity_id`,
  `value` 
FROM
  `catalog_category_entity_<datatype>_1` src 
WHERE src.`store_id` = 1 AND src.value IS NOT NULL
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE 
    `catalog_category_entity_<datatype>`.`value` = src.`value` ;
```

**3)** Then update attributes of categories in Store View #0 based on their counterparts from Store View #1, same situation, run for all tables (I also executed this query for all 3 tables).

```
UPDATE 
  `catalog_category_entity_text` des 
  INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_text` src 
    ON src.`attribute_id` = des.`attribute_id` 
    AND des.`entity_id` = src.`entity_id`     
    AND src.value IS NOT NULL  AND src.value !=""
    SET des.`value` = src.value
WHERE src.store_id = 1 AND des.`store_id`=0;
```

**4)** And finally, remove everything that belongs to store view #1. This will force categories in store #1 to have (Default Value) selected.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_text` WHERE store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_datetime` WHERE store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_decimal` WHERE store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE store_id = 1;
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE store_id = 1;
```